# my modal aren't displaying my content however console log is able to retrieve it

Tags: javascript, simplemodal

I am trying to add modals to my simple js app for a pokedex, however, while it is able to retrieve and log the information from the api, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in order for my modal to display. Please see my code below and I appreciate any help or guidance you could offer!

```
  function showModal(title, text) {
        var modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
        modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
        modalContainer.innerHTML = '';
        var modal = document.createElement('div');
        modal.classList.add('modal');
        var closeButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
        closeButtonElement.classList.add('modal-close');
        closeButtonElement.innerText = 'Close';
        closeButtonElement.addEventListener('click', hideModal);
        var titleElement = document.createElement('h1');
        titleElement.innerText = title;
        var contentElement = document.createElement('p')
        contentElement.innerText = text;
        var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
        imageElement.classList.add('modal-img');
        imageElement.setAttribute('src', item.imageUrl);
        var heightElement = document.createElement('p');
        heightElement.innerText = 'height : ' + item.height + 'm';
        modal.appendChild(closeButtonElement);
        modal.appendChild(titleElement);
        modal.appendChild(contentElement);
        modal.appendChild(nameElement);
        modal.appendChild(imageElement);
        modal.appendChild(heightElement);
        modalContainer.appendChild(modal);
        modalContainer.appendChild('is-visible');
        modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
    }

    document.querySelector('#show-modal').addEventListener('click', () => {
      showModal('modal title', 'this is the modal content');
    });

    function hideModal() {
        var modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
        modalContainer.classList.remove('is-visible');
    };
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
      <title>Simple JS App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul class="pokemon-list"></ul>
      <button id="show-modal">Show Modal</button> 
      <div id="modal-container"></div>
      <script src="js/promise-polyfill.js"></script>
      <script src="js/fetch-polyfill.js"></script>
      <script src="js/scripts1.js"></script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is probably the time of execution. 
Could you please show us your html.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Simple JS App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="pokemon-list"></ul>
    <button id="show-modal">Show Modal</button>
    <div id="modal-container"></div>
    <script src="js/promise-polyfill.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fetch-polyfill.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Your method: "showModal" has multiple undefined variables. (item and nameElement)

You could have figured that out yourself, since the browser actually outputs these errors in the console,

Comment: I don't have any errors in my code when I view it on the console, I was unable to copy all of my code due to the limits on how much I could post in the question, is there anyway that I can upload all of my code here (as I only took out the part that I believe isn't working)?

Comment: or do I need to define the variables inside the function as well?

Comment: You could use jsfiddle and copy a link so we could see all your code.